# About the Enum operation

Tags: c#, enums

I have a enum like

```
enum Test
{ 
    A = -2,
    B = -1 , 
    C = 0 , 
    D = 1 , 
    E = 2
}
```

and , how can i judge a enum value is in a combine enum values

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test t1 = Test.A | Test.E;

        Console.WriteLine((t1 & Test.E) > 0); // true
        Console.WriteLine((t1 & Test.A) > 0); // why this is false ?

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

i want to ask about , why

```
Test t1 = Test.A | Test.E;
```

but

```
Console.WriteLine((t1 & Test.A) > 0);
```

Thanks....

**UPDATE:**

Thank you for your comment , and the good design...

****I think I will change the bad design as sonn as quickly!! ****

****Thank you all the same . (^^ メ)****

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make this work, you have to make sure that the enum-values set different bits since you are doing a bitwise-and operation. Try to define Test like this

```
enum Test
{ 
    A = 1,
    B = 2, 
    C = 4, 
    D = 8, 
    E = 16
}
```

Alternatively.

```
[Flags]
enum Test
{ 
    A = 0x1,
    B = 0x2, 
    C = 0x4, 
    D = 0x8, 
    E = 0x10
}
```

Comment: I don't think the second example does what you think it does.  `A = 0, B = 1, C = 2, ...`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I know if I did I would defined it like that , But I cannt change it now.... sorry...

Comment: Scott - That's the only way to get it work in this way you want. With you enum definition, how can you tell if D is selected alone, or if C and D is selected together? All in all, an enum is just an int, and for D and C,D this int is 2.

Comment: I dont think you're remark about default enum values are correct. From the enum-documentation: "By default, the first enumerator has the value 0, and the value of each successive enumerator is increased by 1.". I can't find an exception for FlagsAttribute.

Comment: Rick - Ops, I thought it did. What is actually the use of the flag then? I'll edit my answer.

Comment: thank you , bros... But I have to wait somebody who can solve the problem. because i cannt change the design now.  (^^ メ)

Comment: @Øyvind: The `[Flags]` primarily affects `ToString()` and [`Enum.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxydatf9.aspx)

Comment: I'll add that .NET 4.0 has `Enum.HasFlag` to check for a flag value It's a shortcut to doing the `& ... == 0`.

Comment: @Scott: The whole point of flags is that they can be combined together and separated again.  If the bits overlap (as yours do) or you have an enum value of zero, then using `|` and `&` is hopeless.  It will never work.

Comment: I found a solution for it , and update the post.   thanks all!!

Comment: Scott - Have you tried your solution for the C+D combination? Or C+anything? That wont work out well even with your new solution.

Comment: @Scott: Your enthusiasm is infectious but your solution is still flawed.  Try `Test t1 = Test.A` and yet `(t1 & Test.D) == Test.D` is `true`!

Comment: @Rick Sladkey yes, you are right ! im wrong.... i would suggest to change the bad design!  thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that `Test.A | Test.E` evaluates to `-2 | 2 = -2`, so `t1 == Test.A`.

Now `t1 & Test.E = -2 & 2 = 2 > 0` and 
`t1 & Test.A = -2 & -2 = -2 < 0`